# Using CustomCell on tableView, how can I get didSelectRowAtIndexPath called?

Tags: iphone, didselectrowatindexpath, custom-cell

I'm populating a UITableView with CustomCells and I'm trying to get didSelectRowAtIndexPath called. Here is the header for the Custom Cell.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet    UILabel         *bizNameLabel;
    IBOutlet    UILabel         *addressLabel;
    IBOutlet    UILabel         *mileageLabel;
    IBOutlet    UIImageView     *bizImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel     *bizNameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel     *addressLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel     *mileageLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *bizImage;
@end
```

Pretty simple and straightforward. I have a detailDisclosureButton I'm adding to the cell as well in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method in the cell as well, and the method `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` is being called, but didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellView" 
                                                     owner:self options:nil];

#ifdef __IPHONE_2_1
        cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
#else
        cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:1];
#endif
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

        /*
          CODE TO POPULATE INFORMATION IN CUSTOM CELLS HERE
       */

#ifdef __IPHONE_3_0
    cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
#endif

    return cell;
}
```

I put an NSLog inside all the methods as well as break points. The method I'm trying to get called is not, but inside my CustomCell class, the following method is. So is there a way to get didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get called while using a CustomCell?

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: is ur UITableView is IBOutlet ??? if so then u should set the delegate like aTableView.delegate = self.

Comment: In IB both the dataSource and delegate outlets are connected to File's Owner. theTableView referencing outlet is connected to File's Owner as well.

Comment: BTW, I'm awestruck that you're supporting iOS 2.1.  You're a better man than I.

Comment: @CABearsfan were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Custom cell or not should not make any difference. Are you in editing mode? If you are, you have to set `allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true` on the tableView.

Comment: Custom Cell was all I could think of. I setup a new view controller and had just default values from an example tutorial plugged in to ensure it worked, and it did fine. Once I created my own array of businesses and changed the contents of cellForRowAtIndexPath the method no longer works. No idea why...

Comment: Also just to ensure it, I put the following lines of code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

theTableView.allowsSelection = TRUE;
theTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = TRUE;

Still not able to call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Also, since `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated ` is being called inside the CustomCell class, is there anyway to relay that to the tableView, or workaround the fact the method I need is not being called using this method? I tried getting it to display the business name within the cell by setting the value of an NSString to self.bizNameLabel.text, but came up blank.

Comment: thank you smparkes, got mad about this issues since 2 hours.. edit mode is enabled in my case. thank you for the hint

Answer (score 0):

if you are use Tableview in your xib..so u want to give tableview's data source and delegate connection in file owner..

Comment: I have both dataSource and delegate connections set to File's Owner in my xib. Also theTableView is connected to File's Owner as the Referencing Outlet

Comment: Also, since `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated ` is being called inside the CustomCell class, is there anyway to relay that to the tableView, or workaround the fact the method I need is not being called using this method? I tried getting it to display the business name within the cell by setting the value of an NSString to self.bizNameLabel.text, but came up blank.

Comment: use cell.bizNameLabel.text=@"string";

Comment: I was looking for a way to retrieve the value of the business name in the cell, not set it.

Comment: ok so try it..
yourstring=((CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).bizNameLabel.Text

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` is getting called, we know that your tableView's delegate property is properly set.  So `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` should be getting called as well.  If it isn't getting called, my best guess is that you have a typo somewhere in the method signature.  Copy and paste this method signature into your code to make sure you didn't accidentally omit the "tableView:" part or make a capitalization error.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

---

EDIT: Secondary hypothesis:  In the .xib where you've defined your custom cell, make sure "User Interaction Enabled" is checked.

Comment: I know there is no reason why it's not being called, which is why I'm so confused. The typing is correct, as when I had the standard prebuilt array populating the table without the Custom Cell it fired no problem. As soon as I changed it to an array built off my JSON return and made the cell type CustomCell it no longer calls the method. Here is the call below as I couldn't put it here due to character limits

Comment: Cleaner
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 NSLog(@"Row Tapped");
 
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Row Tapped" 
             message:@"Success!" 
               delegate:nil 
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];
}`

Comment: Hmm...  Ok, I edited my answer above with something else you can check.

Comment: Yep, user interaction enabled is indeed checked. Like I said, before I changed the data going into the cells from an array I typed out to one I got from PHP call returning JSON it worked fine. As soon as I changed the data to be displayed and made it a custom cell (so i could format it the way i wanted) it stopped firing the desired method

Comment: Also, since `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated ` is being called inside the CustomCell class, is there anyway to relay that to the tableView, or workaround the fact the method I need is not being called using this method? I tried getting it to display the business name within the cell by setting the value of an NSString to self.bizNameLabel.text, but came up blank.

Comment: Try temporarily commenting out the custom cell nib loading code and replacing it with a basic `[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:]`.  That test should tell us if the nib is the culprit.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely the nib. I used the basic default code above and removed all of the code customizing my cell and just displayed the business name as a string (no other info I need to see if it would work) and the method fired just fine.

Comment: Also User Interaction Enabled is checked on the Custom Cell nib as well.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have a UITapGestureRecognizer set for myTableView's parent view ..that is probably over riding the touch event and consuming it.